# Workalendar library: is there a way to automatically 'translate' ISO code to regions to get their holidays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking at this documentation: https://workalendar.github.io/workalendar/iso-registry.html

The problem I'm facing is that they use ISO abbreviations and English names of the regions.

This is the code that's working, but after bunch of edits/trials, I'm having difficulties with the ISO <> English translations.

```
from workalendar.registry import registry
calendars = registry.get_calendars()
import pandas as pd

regions = registry.get_calendars(include_subregions = True)
df_regions = pd.DataFrame(regions.keys())
df_regions.to_csv(r".\holiday_regions.csv", index = False)
```

You can see from above that I save ISO abbreviated regions as a `.csv` file, but the following link uses English names (instead of ISO) to import holiday dates: https://workalendar.github.io/workalendar/advanced.html

Ok so there is a bit of a disconnect between these two, though 'Iterate over the whole registry' section shows that they can be translated so:

```
>>> calendars = registry.get_calendars()  # This returns a dictionary
>>> for code, calendar_class in calendars.items():
>>>     print(f"`{code}` is code for {calendar_class.name!r}")
`AT` is code for 'Austria'
`BE` is code for 'Belgium'
...
```

But how can I do this for sub-regions and save it as `.csv`? I would like to retrieve the list of subregions, save it as `.csv`, and all of these sub-regions should be compatible with the following code (quoting from the documentation, which uses English):

```
>>> from workalendar.europe import France
>>> cal = France()
>>> cal.find_following_working_day(date(2018, 7, 6))  # It's FRI
datetime.date(2018, 7, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
>>> from workalendar.registry import registry
>>> calendars = registry.get_calendars()
>>> calendars["FR"]
<class 'workalendar.europe.france.France'>
```

You will see that you can go from ISO code to calendar by lookup.

When you do this

```
>>> from workalendar.europe import France
>>> France
<class 'workalendar.europe.france.France'>
```

you will see you get exactly the same class back from `from workalendar.europe import France`.

So you do not need the `import` statement. Do the lookup *instead* of the import using the territory name.  To demonstrate this:

```
>>> from workalendar.europe import France
>>> France_by_lookup = calendars["FR"]
>>> France_by_looup is France
True
```

Comment: I understand this, but 'France' and 'FR' are input by the coder -- hard-coded.
I would like to them to be variable, say 'France' and it would automatically substitute into `calendars["FR"]` automatically

Comment: You can't pass a variable to the `import` statement. (You can use `importlib.import_module()` instead, but that is not going to get you far in this case.) You have 2 options. 1. Turn the ISO code tables (ISO 3166-1 and ISO 3166-2, named and linked in the documentation you cite) into dictionaries, and use them to translate `"France"` into `"FR"`. 2.  You could do `mycalendar 
 = getattr(getattr(workalendar,"europe"),"France")` but that looks very ugly to me. But  going against the grain of the API like this leaves me a bit baffled.